# A lock is preventing me from installing ClamAV on Ubuntu Studio 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I cannot install clamav on ubuntu studio 20.04.  Seems to be a "front-end" lock in folder "var/lib/dpkg"  What is this lock, and how do i unlock it to install my AV?

Comment: Try running the command as `sudo apt install clamav`

Answer (score 2):

There are times when the OS runs auto-updates. When that happens, it will `apt-get install <new packages>` (mainly Linux kernels). While doing that installation, it blocks you from using `apt-get` *again*.

As mentioned by Terrance, you could try running the command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install clamav
```

which is not a bad idea since the error in that case is likely going to be much clearer.

One way to see whether `apt` is already running is to use:

```
ps -ef | grep apt
```

or use `htop` (you should see `apt` near the top, you can also filter by typing <kbd>F4</kbd> and then entering `apt` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.) I often use `htop` in order to see when `apt` is done and then run my own commands.

Without `htop`, you can use `watch 'ps -ef | grep apt'`. Ubuntu has `watch` installed by default, not `htop`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mr,. Wilke..  I ran :"sudo apt tnstall clamav" and it worked this time.  I appreciate the explanation.  I do not see the app listed when i pull down the "all applications" menu in the upper left corner of my desktop.  Although the Terminal Emulator indicated it had installed, I'm not sure where to go to actually set parameters in ClamAV.  Forgive my naivety, as I am brand new to Linux.  I was proficient in the Windows world, but now I'm the new guy.  Thanks for your nelp.

Comment: @MikeStevens The graphical application you are looking for to control ClamAV is `clamtk`.  `sudo apt install clamtk` then you should see it in your applications.

Comment: Terrance...  from the information in your last comment i was able to install ClamTK virus scanner.  I appreciate your help on this.  Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: @MikeStevens beside background update service, running APT/DPKG without superuser level (from root or using `sudo`) may raise same error message